How to connect NPHIES FHIR OBB(Testing) Server in order to submit eligibility/preauthorization/claims and soon
I am facing issue while downloading the recent transactions submitted by the provider. In my previous project the end point was defined clearly about the input params. But in this implementation i am very new to FHIR
I want to know how i can get the transaction which are submitted between two dates

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
